# Coldfusion Merge Results from database with store info and store hours, I know I'm missing it

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

My experience with QofQ is limited, to say the least. I can really use some help and am not giving any excuses. Thank you in advance. To make things clearer I got rid of many of the search requirements to simply matters, obliviously 20 is not the only criteria in selecting a business.

I have two databases one for stores and their info, and another database for store hours. Ideally, I would like to merge the results of the store with the store hours. Note: not all stores have hours yet, and stores do not have the same days or hours when open, so when I look up the hours table, I look for results from my list that match the "businessID" and "dayWeek" from the "hoursopen" database.

DATABASES:

1. "businesses" contains id [Key], bus_name, bus_address, bus_city, bus_phone. I limit the results to 20 per page (obviously the 20 is replaced by a variable)

DATA EXAMPLE:

- 1001, ABC, 123 Main Street, New York, 212-555-1212
- 1002, NBC, 246 Elm Street, Long Island, 516-555-1212
- 1003, CBS, 369 Ave P, Brooklyn, 718-555-1212

2. "hoursopen" contains id [Key], "businessID" matches database "businesses" id [Key], timeZone (to adjust for time zones), dayWeek (select only today's hours), openTime, and closeTime
   DATA EXAMPLE:

- 3, 1001, 1, 5, 09:00:00, 21:00:00
- 4, 1001, 1, 6, 09:00:00, 21:00:00
- 5, 1001, 1, 7, 10:00:00, 16:00:00

CODE:

````
<cfquery name="businesses" datasource="businesses"> 
         SELECT id, bus_name, bus_address, bus_city, bus_phone
         FROM businesses
         WHERE id < 20
</cfquery>
            
<!-- 1st Query businesses (id) that were found to search in the hoursopen database, 
note that the two results are not in the same order-->
            <cfscript>
                businessResults=ValueList(businesses.id)
            </cfscript>  
            
<cfquery name="hoursopen" datasource="hoursopen"> 
    SELECT *
    FROM hoursopen
    WHERE businessID IN ( 
                        <cfqueryparam 
                            value="#businessResults#" 
                            cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER"
                            list="yes" 
                            />
                            ) AND dayWeek = dayOfWeek(Now())      
</cfquery>

<!-- In the results I bolded the BusinessID to Illustrate the relationship.-->

<p>------ BUSINESS LOCATION & PHONE ------ </p>
 <cfoutput query="businesses">
            <strong>Business ID: #id#</strong><br/>
            Business Name: #bus_name#<br/>
            Address: #bus_address#<br/>
            City: #bus_city#<br/>
            Phone: #bus_phone#<br/>
            <hr/>    
            </cfoutput>
    
<p>------ BUSINESS HOURS ------ </p>
<cfoutput query = "hoursopen">
     <p>ID: #id# | <strong>Business ID: #businessID# </strong>| Time Zone: #timeZone# | 
        Day of the Week: #dayWeek# | Store Opens: #openTime# | Store Closes: #closeTime#</p>
     <hr/>
</cfoutput>```
````

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing what you are describing, I would probably do it the following way. Basically I would run the business query, put those results into an array of structures. As I am doing so, I would get the hours for each business, and put those in to an array of structures as well. The code would look like the following. Please know I have not tested this at all but this is the typical way I do this kind of work:

```
    <cffunction name="getBusinessHours" returntype="array">
        <cfargument name="_id" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="_dayWeek" type="string" required="yes">

        <cfquery name="_qHours">
            select  * from  hoursopen
            where   businessId = <cfqueryparam value="#_id#" cfsqltype="integer"> and
                    dayWeek = <cfqueryparam value="#_dayWeek#" cfsqltype="varchar">
            order by 
                    dayWeek
        </cfquery>

        <cfset _hours = arrayNew(1)>
        <cfloop query="_qHours">
            <cfset _hour = structNew()>
            <cfset _hour['id'] = id>
            <cfset _hour['timeZone'] = timeZone>
            <cfset _hour['dayWeek'] = dayWeek>
            <cfset _hour['openTime'] = openTime>
            <cfset _hour['closeTime'] = closeTime>

            <cfset arrayAppend(_hours, _hour)>
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn _hours>
    </cffunction>


    <cfquery name="_qBusinesses">
        select * from businesses   //limit query as needed
    </cfquery>


    <cfset _businesses = ArrayNew(1)>

    <cfloop query="_qBusinesses">
        <cfset _business = structNew()>
        <cfset _business['id'] = id>
        <cfset _business['name'] = bus_name>
        <cfset _business['address'] = bus_address>
        <cfset _business['city'] = bus_city>
        <cfset _business['phone'] = bus_phone>

        <cfset _business['hours'] = getBusinessHours(id, dayOfWeek(Now())>

        <cfset arrayAppend(_businesses,_business)>

    </cfloop>

    <cfoutput>
        <cfloop array="_businesses" index="_b">
            <strong>Business ID: #_b.id#</strong><br/>
            Business Name: #_b.name#<br/>
            Address: #_b.address#<br/>
            City: #_b.city#<br/>
            Phone: #_b.phone#<br/>
            <hr/>    
                
            
            <p>------ BUSINESS HOURS ------ </p>
            <cfloop array="_b.hours" index="_h" >
                <p>ID: #_h.id# | <strong>Business ID: #_b.id# </strong>| Time Zone: #_h.timeZone# | 
                    Day of the Week: #_h.dayWeek# | Store Opens: #_h.openTime# | Store Closes: #_h.closeTime#</p>
                <hr/>
            </cfloop>
        </cfloop>    
    </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain a QoQ is needed? You didn't mention your dbms or configuration, but if the two db's are on the same server you might able to query one from within the other directly. In which case all you need is a JOIN.

```
 SELECT b.id, b.bus_name, b.bus_address, b.bus_city, b.bus_phone
        , h.timeZone, h.dayOfWeek, h.openTime, h.closeTime
 FROM   databaseA.owner.businesses b
            LEFT JOIN databaseB.owner.hoursopen h ON h.businessID = b.id 
            AND h.dayWeek = dayOfWeek(Now())
 WHERE b.id < 20
 ORDER BY b.bus_name, h.dayOfWeek
```

> Note: not all stores have hours yet

If that's not possible, a QoQ probably isn't the best option here, because they don't support [OUTER JOIN's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join). A simple alternative is dump the hours data into a structure of structures, using business id as the key. Then simply lookup the hours by business id.

[Example](https://trycf.com/gist/63e00fd8af58f10c74e9cd31a24b4101/lucee5?theme=monokai)

```
<!--- store hours by business id  --->
<cfset businessHours = {}>
<cfloop from="1" to="#hoursOpen.recordCount#" index="x">
    <cfset rowData = hoursOpen.getRow( x )>
    <cfset businessHours[ rowData.businessId ] = rowData>
</cfloop>

 <cfoutput query="businesses">
    <p>------ BUSINESS LOCATION & PHONE ------ </p>
    <strong>Business ID: #id#</strong><br/>
    Business Name: #bus_name#<br/>
    Address: #bus_address#<br/>
    City: #bus_city#<br/>
    Phone: #bus_phone#<br/>

    <!--- if we found hours for this business --->
    <cfif businessHours.keyExists( businesses.id )>
        <cfset hoursData = businessHours[ businesses.id ]>
        <p>------ BUSINESS HOURS ------ </p>
        <p>ID: #hoursData.id# 
            | <strong>Business ID: #hoursData.businessID# </strong>
            | Time Zone: #hoursData.timeZone# 
            | Day of the Week: #hoursData.dayWeek# 
            | Store Opens: #hoursData.openTime# 
            | Store Closes: #hoursData.closeTime#
        </p>
    </cfif>

    <hr/>    
 </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SOS and snackboy.

I was out sick with Corona and just returned to reality when that Sunday I got a call that my best friend unveiling at his grave was taking place. So your help really was appreciated.

Now that I've played with both ideas, I came across an interesting concept. You cannot do a CFOUTPUT within a CFOUTPUT but there is a loophole literally.

Because there is such a small amount of data it's the same as creating all those arrays.

```
<cfloop
    query = "hoursopen">
    <cfif businessID IS businesses.id>
   ...
</cfloop>
```

Love to hear some feedback.

Comment: When adding followup comments to a question its better to go to the bottom of your original post and "Add Comment" as opposed to posting a new Answer. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Hope you're feeling better.  TBH, I am allergic to looping unnecessarily (-:.  Just curious, but why not just throw the hours data into a structure and look it up by key? It's [only about 5 lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69431313/8895292) and should scale better than a loop within a loop.  With a limit of 20 businesses, the structure approach performs a max of 40 iterations, whereas the "loop within a loop" iterates _400_ times. That means if you increase the number of businesses to say 50, the latter would iterate 2500 times!